# Unable to update Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: upgrade, updates

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 ,when I use apt-get install I am getting error as `Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Answer (score 0):

10.10 is dead. It's end-of-life date was some day in July 2011. That's the reason why many repositories don't have any compatible software (updates) any more.

Please upgrade to a newer and supported version. You may chose between:

- 15.04 (will be released 26/04/2015; supported 9 months until 01/2016)
- 14.10 (released 10/2014; supported 9 months until 07/2015)
- 14.04 LTS (released 04/2014; supported 5 years until 04/2019)
- [*12.04 LTS (released 04/2012; supported 5 years until 04/2017)* ]

You may visit https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases for further details.